# html css Position foreground

Tags: html, css

The "Home" is  tag and I want it behind the menu. How can I do it?

[image]
The above image shows how the site currently looks like.

Here is my CSS Code used currently in the site:

```
  ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 19.86%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

    ul li ul li{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

    h1 {
    top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Comment: your html code?

Comment: try instead  `z-index:5;` use `z-index:-1;`

Comment: isn't it already at the background? can you provide an image how you would like it took like? keep in mind that its white will show through the layers above, maybe you just want to reduce its `opacity`?

Comment: z-index 101: It only works on positioned elements. So you would at least need to add `position:relative` to your `ul li ul li` here. (But it might make more sense maybe to apply it to the outermost menu container element in the first place, instead of to the submenu items individually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `z-index:5;` use `z-index:-1;` to `h1`

and remove `z-index:10;` from `ul li ul li` (not needed)

```css
ul li {
float: left;
width: 19.86%;
background-color: black;
opacity: .8;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
border: 1px solid white;
}

ul li ul li{
display: none;
width:100%;
}

h1 {
top: 1px;
left:50px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
font-size: 65px;
font-weight: bold;
z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<h1>Home</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set your `h1` `z-index: 1`. And then set `z-index: 2` to first `ul` with black background.
Like:

```
h1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
ul {
    z-index: 2;
}
```